JSX and TSX syntax highlighting in Spyder
I'm using Spyder for a React project. The problem is that .tsx and .jsx files are not syntax-highlighted, and I don't know how to turn that on.
If I rename them to .ts and .js, they look good. So, it's only about including those extensions to some list, but where...?
